# Faillog - unsuccessful login count in Motd

Tags: bash, shell, security, logs, motd

I wish to include a count of failed login attempts whenever a user logs in.

I've created:

```
/usr/local/bin/dynmotd
```

which contains

```
#!/bin/bash

FAILLOG=`faillog -u`

echo -e "
$FAILLOG
"
```

and added `/usr/local/bin/dynmotd` to `/etc/profile`

The issue is I get `/var/log/faillog: Permission denied`

whenever I login as a regular user. Is there a way to either safely temporarily escalate privileges to run that command on the motd, or temporarily give that user access to faillog to get that response? I don't want to give all user access to faillog permanently.

**UPDATE**

Tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENTUSER=`whoami`

sudo -u bob setfacl -m u:$CURRENTUSER:rx /var/log/faillog

FAILLOG=`sudo -u bob faillog -u $CURRENTUSER`

echo -e "
$FAILLOG
"
```

Add added 'bob' to the sudoers with `NOPASSWD:`, this works fine when I'm logging in as 'bob' but if I try and login as 'bob2' I get asked for the sudoers password.

Comment: Seeing the message `permission denied` I think you can  `setfacl -m u:username:r /var/log/faillog`  to grant `read` access to the particular user.

Comment: Adding `setfacl -m u:'whoami':rx /var/log/faillog`  gives me a setfacl: /var/log/faillog: Operation not permitted

Comment: `setfacl` should be run as root user. 'whoami' is not as  `whoami` and you should not use it there. Instead use a real username you want to grant read privileges to that file.

Comment: Tried running it as sudo, as I can't run it as root as the user won't know (or be allowed) the root password. Updated question.

Comment: Seems you don't understand what I'm trying to explain. You first need to be root then grant read permissions to a particular user for example to `kiksy`. You don't need to modify the script. It will be able to read the file.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you. How can I trigger the script to be run as root? in my `/etc/profile` file?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a script that runs as root.  Have it run hourly, writing the output of 'faillog -a' to a text file everyone has access to.  Then have your MOTD grep that file for the current user.  This would avoid having to make any unnecessary permissions changes or granting someone sudo access that doesn't need it.